# Cleanup values on export with SQL (if null or similar)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently building a select query to transport some data from an old clumsy db structure with quite some noise and trash in it into a new app. While things come together quite well generally I also want to cleanup some stuff.

Two varchar(50) fields contain geo coordinates. You won't be surprised they are named latitude and longitude and there ideal values look a bit like this: 10.9627823122

I already found out i could handle them like this:

```
CAST(mytable.`longitude` as DECIMAL(16,12))
```

Which works out great but unfortunately there are some rows that had empty values before and now get formed to 0.000000000000 and also some that contained nonsense so far (like silly texts, urls and other stuff) as the script didn't do any checks on the input side. I'd prefer to have these fields set to NULL insead of 0.00000000000. I could of course do this with a simple search/replace on the resulting CSV export file but I'd prefer to know how to do it in SQL if possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if(longitutude <> '', cast(...), null)`, basically. but note that CSV can't represent sql nulls, and you'll just end up with an empty string in the output, and are right back to the same thing again.

Comment: an empty string is totally ok for that - still better than 0.00000000 which isn't an empty string at the end :) Anways - thanks for helping, that works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B posted in the comments here's the way to do it:

```
if(mytable.`longitude` <> '', CAST(mytable.`longitude` as DECIMAL(16,12)), null)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: still getting used to SO - can't mark my own answer as a solution but... well it is - so maybe someone else can? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the data as you export it with this:

```
  Select top 10
    Case CAST(mytable.`longitude` as DECIMAL(16,12)) = 0.000000000000
      when 0.000000 then NUll
      else CAST(mytable.`longitude` as DECIMAL(16,12)) = 0.000000000000
    End 
    from myTable
```

Comment: As I wrote above I only want this to be in the output, not changed in the DB, so the UPDATE way isn't working for me. Thanks anways for helping.